# Append image to div in Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, class

I want to append an image to a div using Jquery and my code looks like this:

```
$(".contentdiv")[div].append('<img src="china.jpg" class="contentimg">')
```

This doesn't return an error, but doesn't display the image either. When I remove the [div] iterator it does work, but I don't want to do that because I might want to use different images for different contentdivs in the future. 
The problem is not in the [div] though, because

```
$(".contentdiv")[div].style.marginLeft = 30px
```

works fine.

Comment: so what is `[div]` ?? number??

Comment: Try: `$(".contentdiv")[div].append("<img src='china.jpg' class='contentimg'>")` (note the quotes being used.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the jQuery object, not just the element in the collection returned. @jafarbtech has a good solution, but you could also just wrap what you have now in `$()` to create an object out of it so you can use it with `$.append()`

```js
var div = 1;
$($(".contentdiv")[div]).append('<img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="contentimg">');
$(".contentdiv")[div].style.marginLeft = '30px';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentdiv"></div>
<div class="contentdiv"></div>
<div class="contentdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.eq()` to append different image in different `contentdiv` by using `$(".contentdiv").eq(0).append('<img src="http://placehold.it/140x158" class="contentimg">');`

```js
$(".contentdiv").eq(0).append('<img src="http://placehold.it/140x158" class="contentimg">');
$(".contentdiv").eq(1).append('<img src="http://placehold.it/150x158" class="contentimg">');
$(".contentdiv").eq(2).append('<img src="http://placehold.it/160x158" class="contentimg">');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentdiv">
</div>

<div class="contentdiv">
</div>

<div class="contentdiv">
</div>
```